# Stored function not returning a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-functions

I'm trying to create a stored function called `func_GetMenuItemsForMenu`.

For this function, I need to pass the ID of the menu to it. The function will find all MenuItems that are on the menu. It will return a table.

Here is what I have tried:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[func_GetMenuItemsForMenu] 
    (@MenuItemMenuItemID NVARCHAR(200))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
   RETURN (SELECT Menu.MenuID 
           FROM Menu, MenuItem
           WHERE MenuItem.MenuID LIKE @MenuItemMenuItemID + '%'
             AND MenuItem.MenuID = Menu.MenuID)
GO
```

Here is my table structure:

[image: Table Structure]

I'm only getting the MenuID and it's not returning the menu item as well that's on the specific menu.

Comment: Because only have Menu.MenuID in the `SELECT` list.... you should also [use explicit joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). Your old-style join has really, really old.

Comment: My bad, I'm really new to stored functions and procedures.

Comment: No problem, but this would be the same for any `select` statement. Only the columns listed between `select` and `from` would be returned. Change `SELECT Menu.MenuID FROM Menu...` to `SELECT Menu.MenuID, MenuItem.MenuItemTitle FROM Menu...` or what ever column you want to return.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not select the columns you need and that is why you only get `MenuID`.
I add `MenuItemTitle` here.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[func_GetMenuItemsForMenu] 
(
    @MenuItemMenuItemID NVARCHAR(200)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
    SELECT 
        Menu.MenuID, 
        MenuItem.MenuItemTitle 
    FROM Menu
    INNER JOIN 
        MenuItem ON 
        MenuItem.MenuID = Menu.MenuID
    WHERE
        MenuItem.MenuID LIKE @MenuItemMenuItemID + '%')
GO
```